# Continuous functions, its inverse (if exists) and intersections graphically

Tags: functions

I have a question regarding graphical intersection between a continuous function and its inverse (if exists).

Suppose $f$ is a real continuous function and $f^{-1}$ exists.

Can anyone assist in proving the following problem:

If $f$ and $f^{-1}$ intersect graphically at some points, then the points must lie on the line $y=x$.(*)

For here, I have some trouble regarding the meaning of "some" points.

If it is uncountable many points of intersection, $y=\frac{1}{x}$ is a counterexample.

What if it is countable (including finite many or countably infinite)?

Intuitively, (*) is true when we draw the functions pictorially, but can anyone provide hints or steps to the proof?

If the statement is wrong at the first place, how should we amend?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by the intersection of two functions? Do you mean the intersection of their graphs? If so, please edit that into the body of the question.

Comment: Surely there must be some condition on f, otherwise let f be a function that swaps two given reals and fixes all the others

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Perhaps I change the question to continuous functions.

Comment: @Belgi I'm missing how that is a counter example. As far as I can tell, all points $a$ such that $f(a)=f^{-1}(a)$ are in $\{(x,x)\colon x\in \mathbb R\}$.

Comment: Also, $f(a)=f^{-1}(a)$ doesn't mean the point of intersections are on line $y=x$, a counterexample will be $y=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: @GitGud the point is (a, f(a)), say f swaps 0 and 1, then f agrees with its inverse for all reals, but does not coincide with y=x(excuse me for the lack of tex, I'm using a mobile phone)

Comment: @Belgi You're right, I made a geometric mistake in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graphical proof can be algebra-fied: Let's look at a certain $x=x_1$ where $f(x_1)=x_1$ i.e. $f(x)$ intersects the $y=x$ at that $x_1$. Now since they intersect we have $x_1-f(x_1)=0 \Rightarrow x_1=f(x_1)$. Now we take the inverse $f^{-1}$ of both sides: $f^{-1}(x_1)=x_1 \Rightarrow f^{-1}(x_1)-x_1=0$ which means $f^{-1}(x)$ also intersects the $y=x$ line at that $x_1$ which means $f(x)$ intersects $f^{-1}(x)$ on the line $y=x$.

An alternative solution would be to say that in order for an intersection to take place we want $f^{-1}(x)=f(x)$ and the $x$ which satisfies this is where the intersection happens. Taking the $f$ of both sides gives us $x=f(f(x))$ which is a functional equation. Now $f(x)=x$ is a solution to that functional equation which indicates that the intersections happen at $y=x$. The only issue is that I'm not sure how to prove that there are no other solutions to that functional equation.

I hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: By your first paragraph, it seems that you are proving the converse of the statement.

Comment: True, I tried to show that if $f(x)$ intersects $y=x$ then at that point we also have $f(x)$ intersecting $f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: Your second question is the crux. Pictorially it is evident, but $\frac{1}{x}$ is the spoiler.

Comment: Such a function is an involution (I found on Wikipedia). Apparently, $y=-x$ is an involution. The function coincides with its inverse, yet the intersections is the line itself, not $y=x$.

Comment: Which is why we probably cannot show that all intersections take place on the line $y=x$. Interesting problem I must say.

Comment: But if suppose the continuous function and its inverse (if exists) intersect countable many times (be it finite or countably many), perhaps y=x is their intersections. For finitely many, pictorially it helps, but algebraically I cannot prove it. Not to say countably infinite.

Comment: But, what I was trying to get at was that **only** for the $x$'s in which the inverse and the $f$ intersect we have the functional equation $x=f(f(x))$. I guess that should be specified clearly.

Comment: The original problem is something like what you say: if there exists $a$ such that $f(a)=f^{-1}(a)$, then $f(a)=a$.

Comment: Your functional equation has a name. I got it from Wiki:  Babbage's functional equation

Comment: Using $a$ is certainly more clear. Thanks for the functional equation's name. Googled it myself earlier, couldn't find anything on it!

Comment: Haha. Perhaps I am afraid that I might misinterpret it as the intersection only occurs at one point.

Comment: What do you say about the function $f(x)=1-x^3$ and its inverse$f^{-1}(x)=\left(1-x\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$.There is only one point of intersection on $y=x$ whereas the points $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ also are points of intersection which do not lie on $y=x$.There are two more points of intersection. Also,consider the function  $f(x)=\sin x-x$ and its inverse.